# Critical region for testing a hypothesis with exponential data.

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, hypothesis-testing

I have trouble with the following problem:

> We assume that X has a Exp(λ)-distribution with a unknowns value of λ.
>   We test H0: λ=0.2 versus H1: λ < 0.2. We use X as test statistic.  a.
>   Calculate the critical area for alpha = 0.05 b. The measured X=10,
>   calculate the P-value
>   ans: [14.98, infinity) and p = 0.135

I know that the critical area is the collection of values for which H0 is rejected in favor of H1. In the case of a normal distribution I know how to calculate the critical region. Depending on the kind of alternate hypothesis and the significance level I can caluclate the Z-value. With the Z-value I can calculate the X.

Unfortunately I don't know how to do this with an exponential distribution. I have issues with visualising it, since a different λ gives a different curve.

Can I please get some feedback?

Thanks, 
Ter

Comment: Have you derived an appropriate test here?

Comment: Hi @StubbornAtom what do you exactly mean with deriving an appropiate test?

Comment: You are asked for a critical region. What is your critical region?

Comment: That I where I get stuck, I don't exactly know how to calculate the critical region for an exponential distribtution, but I know the final answer is [14.98, infinity)

Comment: What testing procedure do you know? Is $\lambda$ the rate parameter or mean of $X$? The answer given suggests it is the rate parameter and a critical region of the form $\{X:X\ge c\}$ where $c$ is calculated from the size restriction $\alpha=0.05$.

Comment: Hi, can I have another hint? I'm still stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter $\lambda$ in an exponential distribution
is the rate. The mean $\mu = E(X) = 1/\lambda.$

So if you are using a single observation $X \sim \mathsf{Exp}(\lambda)$ to test $H_0$ vs. $H_a$ as
in your question, then the critical region is
of the form $\{X \le c\},$ where the critical value $c$
is chosen so that
$$P(X \ge c\,|\,\lambda_0 = 0.2) = \alpha = 0.05.$$
You can evaluate $c$ using the CDF of $\mathsf{Exp}(\lambda_0 = 0.2)$ or using statistical software.
The result from R, where `qexp` is an exponential
quantile function (inverse CDF).

```
qexp(.95, 0.2)
[1] 14.97866
```

Below is a graph of the Density function of $\mathsf{Exp}(.2),$ along with a dotted vertical red line at $c = 14.98.$
The area under the density curve to the right of this red line is $0.05 = 5\%.$ Your data value at $X = 10$ is shown as a solid blue line. The P-value $0.1353$ is the area to the right of the solid blue line.

[image]

```
1 - pexp(10, .2)
[1] 0.1353353
```

Using the exponential CDF on a calculator, this
is $e^{-.2(10)} = e^{-2} = 0.1353353.$

Your data value does not lie in the critical region, to
the right of the dotted red line, so you do not reject
$H_0$ at the 5% level of significance. Also, because the P-value exceeds 5%, you cannot
reject at the 5% level.

*Note:* The R code for making the plot is shown below.

```
curve(dexp(x,.2), 0, 25, lwd=2, ylab="PDF", 
      main="Density of EXP(rate=0.2)")
  abline(v=0, col="green2")
  abline(h=0, col="green2")
  abline(v = 14.98, col="red", lty="dotted", lwd=2)
  abline(v = 10, col="blue")
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort! The concept of the p-value is still difficult for me. I know that the definition is: probability of obtaining results as extreme as the observed results, assuming that the null hypothesis is correct. In excercises with uniform distribution I look at the > or < of the H1, to know where to calculate the probability.  Back to the definition. I don't understand what meant with  "as extreme"

Comment: In this example. How do I know how to calculate the region right of the blue vertical line instead of the left region? What is the link between "as extreme" from the definition and the left/right side of the vertical blue line?

Comment: Region to right of blue line is P-value has probability $e^{-2} = 0.1353353,$ which you can get on a calculator. Just now edited it into my Answer after some R code. "Extreme values" for your $H_a$ are values toward the right. So the P-value is the area to the _right_ of the vertical blue line.