# The critical region of an exp distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I have trouble with calculating the critical region of an exp distribution. I know that the critical region is the region in which H0 should be rejected in favour of H1.

I also know how to calculate the critical region in an normal and uniform distribution, but exponential distribution is still difficult.

problem:

> We assume that X has an Exp(λ) distribution with unknown λ. We want to
> test H0: λ=0.2 against H1<0.2

a. Calculate the critical region with significance level: 0.05.

So I have to find the region in which H0 should be rejected. If this was an normal distribution I would work with Z-scores and normalising, but this isn't probably going to work with an Exp() distribution.
The answer is [14.98, ∞ ).

Can I have feedback on how to visualise this and come to an answer?

Ter

Comment: Repost of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3715568/321264.

Comment: My answer is at the original posting of your question. Questions in which you have shown what you have already tried tend to get a quicker, more enthusiastic response on this site.